# Is there a way to position the ls_background_image in xrdp.ini?

Tags: xrdp

I'm struggling to configure `xrdp`. The often-recommended "scarygliders" tool doesn't appear to have any mention of `ls_background_image` in sources. `xrdp.ini(5)` doesn't even mention the option, so this is (quite literally) uncharted territory.

I want to position a company logo in the lower *left* on the background. Default xrdp behavior is lower *right*.

Any clues much appreciated!

Comment: fwiw, I'm using ImageMagick with `-type truecolor` outputting a `.bmp` for that image; or save with 24bit option from `gimp`. I'm doing the same with the `ls_logo_filename` to drop the managed `/etc/motd` into an image.

Answer (score 0):

## NOPE

There is no way to position the wallpaper `ls_background` image.

I had the good sense to go looking in the sources. In `xrdp/xrdp_login_wnd.c` there's a simple clause for loading the image, triggered by the config key:

```
        /* Load the background image. */
        /* If no file is specified no default image will be loaded. */
        /* We only load the image if bpp > 8 */
        if (globals->ls_background_image[0] != 0 && self->screen->bpp > 8)
        {
            char fileName[256] ;
            but = xrdp_bitmap_create(4, 4, self->screen->bpp, WND_TYPE_IMAGE, self);
            if (globals->ls_background_image[0] == '/')
            {
                g_snprintf(fileName, 255, "%s", globals->ls_background_image);
            }
            else
            {
                g_snprintf(fileName, 255, "%s/%s",
                           XRDP_SHARE_PATH, globals->ls_background_image);
            }
            log_message(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "We try to load the following background file: %s", fileName);
            xrdp_bitmap_load(but, fileName, self->palette);
            but->parent = self->screen;
            but->owner = self->screen;
            but->left = self->screen->width - but->width;
            but->top = self->screen->height - but->height;
            list_add_item(self->screen->child_list, (long)but);
        }
```

The end of this is very clearly hardcoded to position the image in the lower right. Horizontal position is image width subtracted from screen width; vertical position is image height subtracted from screen height. Using the term *extent* to mean the corner opposite the *origin*, then generally, the image extent will always be at the screen extent. Since the origin is upper left, the image will always appear in the opposite lower right corner.

That answers my question, (and encourages me to submit a 'gravity' patch).

Comment: To the people who edited and approved the edit to remove source code indentation: I prefer source code quotes to be _quotes_, not altered in any way. It's the "pristine source" approach that comes from being an RPM packager. The line that causes the scrollbar to appear is irrelevant, anyway.